# Campo select duplicando com chosen-rails e relacionamento has many through

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Fala pessoal,

Tenho uma tabela GROUP_TV e ela se relaciona com a tabela City através do has many through.

No _from.html.erb da view GROUP_TV, tenho um collection_select para selecionar quantas cidades eu desejar. Isso funciona perfeitamente.

O problema acontece quando eu adiciono a gem do chosen e configuro ela para exibir naquele campo, ele até funciona, mas na página de edição ele duplica, por exemplo:

Se na action NEW eu selecionei as cidades: Americana e Barueri e salvei, na action EDIT aparecem 2 campos SELECT com os mesmos valores em cada, vejam o print abaixo:

[image: Print do erro]

Como eu posso resolver isso?

Segue o código do select

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_ids, City.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Selecione as cidades"}, {:multiple => true, class: "select-chosen"}) %>
```

Comment: Caso você coloque 3 cidades, aparecem 3 selects ou ainda apenas 2?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se reolve seu problema, mas isso ja aconteceu comigo e resolvi no params.permit. usando meu exemplo: :id

```
 params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description,tasks_attributes: [:id, :description, :done, :melhorar, :_destroy])
```

essa duvida é de seis meses atrás, mas alguém pode ter o mesmo problema